# How to manipulate data using GLUT's callbacks

Tags: c++, global-variables, glut, freeglut

I would like to alter a vector using glut's mouse callback (conditionally adding/erasing to/from it), however I can't pass any extra arguments to the callback function, and `glutMainLoop()` which handles all the callbacks takes no arguments. The only way I can imagine to circumvent this is to declare the vector globally, but I've heard this is bad practise, so it is my last resort.

Is this a situation when using a global variable? If so, is there a "best way" to do it? If not, how should I approach this problem.

Comment: Yes, you will probably have to use some static method or some global context. And just for the record, glut is quite old library and there are much better alternatives nowadays, like GLFW.

Comment: Alright, I'll look at using GLFW once I've finished this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, it seems like I can accomplish this with pointers.

Declare globally a pointer to a vector, and inside the callback call the required methods eg. `vector->push_back(x)`

In main, create the vector object and assign its address to the global pointer, and attach your callbacks as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read more about singletons. They are a good way to handle global structures inside a large codebase.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern